# JqGrid - I need to fill my tablecells with a background colour with no padding

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In my JqGrid the background colours are not filling the cells;
[image]

How do I remove the white gaps?
From ie developer tools, the Appears Satisfactory cell is defined as follows

```html
<td title="Appears Satisfactory" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="grid_Recommendation" >
 <span class="ui-jqgrid-cell-wrapper">
  <div class="pass">Appears Satisfactory</div>
 </span>
</td>
```

where the "pass" class is defined as

```
.pass {
    background-color: #C0FF97;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
```

and in javascript my JqGrid is defined as follows;

```
var populateGrid = function (data) {
    var grid = $("#grid");
    grid.jqGrid({
        data: data,
        colNames: ["No", "Company", "Trade", "Recommendation", ""],
        colModel: [
            { name: "AssessmentNo", label: "AssessmentNo", width:80, align:"center" },
            { name: "Company", label: "Company", width:400, searchoptions: { sopt: ["cn"] } },
            { name: "Trade", label: "Trade", width: 220, searchoptions: { sopt: ["cn"] } },
            { name: "Recommendation", label: "Recommendation", width: 150 },
            { name: "Links", label: "Links", search: false, align: "center" }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { width: 100, autoResizable: true },
        loadonce: true,
        forceClientSorting: true,
        rowNum: 20,
        pager: "#pager",
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        rownumbers: true,
        sortname: "AssessmentNo",
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        height: "100%"
    });

    grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
        beforeSearch: function () {
            return false; // allow filtering
        }
    }).jqGrid("gridResize");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code don't contain the most important part where you set the class `"pass"`. I can guess that you set it in the wrong way.

What you seems to want is setting class attribute on the cell (`<td>` element) under some condition. The `cellattr` callback in the `colModel` is exact way to do this. If the choice of the class depend on the content of the cell then you can do the followin

```js
{
    name: "Recommendation", label: "Recommendation", width: 150,
    cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue) {
        if (cellValue === "Appears Satisfactory") {
            return " class='pass'";
        } else if (cellValue === "Expired") {
            return " class='not-pass'";
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to test some other properties of input data then you can use

```js
{
    name: "Recommendation", label: "Recommendation", width: 150,
    cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rawObject, cm, item) {
        // item.AssessmentNo, item.Company and other are filled here
        if (item.Recommendation === "Appears Satisfactory") {
            return " class='pass'";
        } else if (item.cellValue === "Expired") {
            return " class='not-pass'";
        }
    }
}
```

where `item` contains parsed (read) object with input data and `rawObject` contains raw object with input data. The `rawObject` can be array of strings or XML node instead of the `item`, which contains always named properties line the column names.

If you would use `cellattr` then you will get HTML fragment like

```html
<td class="pass" title="Appears Satisfactory" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="grid_Recommendation">
    <span class="ui-jqgrid-cell-wrapper">Appears Satisfactory</span>
</td>
```

Finally I should remark that free jqGrid which you use allows you to simplify your current code. First of all the options `loadonce: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` have sense only if you use some **remote** `datatype` ("json", "jsonp" or "xml"). It will be ignored with `datatype: "local"` which you use. In the same way you can *remove* `gridview: true, ignoreCase: true, sortorder: "asc", height: "100%"` options which are default in free jqGrid. You can remove `<div id="pager"></div>` and just use `pager: true` instead of `pager: "#pager"`. The smaller the code the more easy it will be to read and to maintain.